# Как в boost.beast получить полный текст запроса?

Tags: c++, boost, boost.asio

У меня есть вот такой вот код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <string.h>
using namespace boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http = beast::http;           // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace net = boost::asio;            // from <boost/asio.hpp>
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;       // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>



boost::asio::io_context ioc;

int main() {
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioc, tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(),
                                                                            8000)));
    beast::error_code ec;
    int count = 0;
    while(count < 1) {
        tcp::socket socket(ioc);
        acceptor.accept(socket);
        beast::flat_buffer buffer;
        http::request<http::string_body> req;
        http::read(socket, buffer, req, ec);
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

как мне получить полный текст запроса ?

Comment: ну так а в буффере у вас что?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, а как его преобразовать в нормальынй тип данных, котоыйр я могу вывести или посмотреть. Я пытался с помощью std::cout << beast::buffers(buffer.data()); но не получается, хотя в документации напсиано, что должно работать

Comment: что значит "не получается"?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, компилятор говорит, что << синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, /home/anton/dev/beast_test2/main.cpp:33:19: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘void’)
   33 |         std::cout << beast::buffers(buffer.data()) << std::endl;
      |         ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              |                     |
      |              |                     void
      |              std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}

Comment: а где в документации написано что это должно работать?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__buffers.html

Comment: а хидер то подключили?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, да, подключил. Наверное версия не та, я использовал make_printable, но все равно на выходе пустая строка